# Python "with" statement causes error in Visual Studio

Tags: python, with-statement

im useing Python (3.9) in combination with Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019
Version 16.7.7

I try to use an example to write a config file. https://tutswiki.com/read-write-config-files-in-python/

Visual Studio is reporting me an syntax error at the keywords "open" an "as" and the ":" in the end of the line. Marks it red. There also is no highlight on the "with" and the "as" statement.
If i force Visual Studio to run anyway, it is running fine.

Does anyone know, what's the problem Visual Studio is reporting and how to fix it.

```
from configparser import ConfigParser

#Get the configparser object
config_object = ConfigParser()

#Assume we need 2 sections in the config file, let's call them USERINFO and SERVERCONFIG
config_object["USERINFO"] = {
    "admin": "Chankey Pathak",
    "loginid": "chankeypathak",
    "password": "tutswiki"
}

config_object["SERVERCONFIG"] = {
    "host": "tutswiki.com",
    "port": "8080",
    "ipaddr": "8.8.8.8"
}

#Write the above sections to config.ini file
with open('config.ini', 'w') as conf:
    config_object.write(conf)
```

Comment: Is your IDE configured to a particular ancient version of Python? `with` statements were added in Python 2.5, in 2006. Double check the expected version in your IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Silvio, you pushed me in the correct direction.

I added Python 3.9 (64Bit) to my project. While installation of Visual Studio i also selected the 64Bit version of Python3 (not the latest version available--> 3.7.8).

But Visual Studios installation path is:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe

Because of the "(x86)" i tried to install the 32bit Python3 while installation of Visual Studio.

Now it works fine!